# Is there a way to add a custom group to Finder's sidebar in Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, finder, sidebar

Does anybody know if it is possible to add a custom group to Finder's sidebar in Mac OS X 10.7 (Lion)?

Currently you have *Favorites*, *Shared* and *Devices*. I'd like to add something like *Clients* or *Projects*.

Comment: You can't even rearrange the groups, so I don't think it's happening. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3200109

Comment: As a workaround, I use *Sidebar Separators* (no longer available for download AFAICT), applications that do nothing when started and have `————————` as name. Not particularly nice to look at, but it makes separating favorites easier. Respond if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote small app for myself, you may create different fav sets with it and switch between them. I have about 5 projects myself, so it helps me well. I did not public it, you may try it by [this link](http://mavrsoft.com/PlacesGrouper/PlacesGrouper.zip).